# Html rendering order for asp mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How come my form loads like this?

[image]

Here is my code :

```
@using MvcApplication6.Models;
@model List<Employee>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>
<p>
    <a href="@Url.Action("Create")">Create Entry</a>
</p>
<p>@Html.ActionLink("Check departments", "Index", "Department")</p>
<p><a href="@Url.Action("Summary")">Check summary</a></p>

<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].id)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model[0].firstname)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model[0].lastname)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].gender)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].department)
        </th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        foreach (Employee mod in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" value="@mod.id" name="id" id="id" />
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => mod.id)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => mod.firstname)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => mod.lastname)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => mod.gender)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => mod.department)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Edit", new { id = mod.id })';return false;">Edit</button> 

                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => mod.selected)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    }
    </table>
```

Here are my concerns:

Notice that i put my `submit` button after the `foreach` loop but how come it was rendered first before the actual boxes?
I've been trying to put it on the bottom but i am having some problems.
What's the ordering for render?

Comment: You have invalid html. A `<form>` element cannot be a child of a `<table>` element (nor the elements generated by `AntiForgeryToken` and `ValidationSummary`. But this will never bind to anything if you submitted the form anyway!

Comment: oooo really, how should i fix it? yea i am working on that issue as well.

Comment: What is the purpose of the form and the related checkboxes (what information do you need when you submit)?

Comment: Alright let me fix my question. I will delete this one and make another question since i fixed it somehow.